# Passing Parameters to AJAX script and specify DIV to update

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a simple HTML table with a column showing a Yes/No option-  when a user changes the Yes to No or vice versa it should call a simple PHP script via AJAX which updates the record in the database.

Here's how the table looks like:

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Description</th>
        <th scope="col">Type</th>
        <th scope="col">Completed</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Welcome Email</td>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td>
            <div class="radio" id="radio1">
                <label><input checked id="1" name="completed1" type="radio" value="Yes">Yes</label>
                <label><input id="1" name="completed1" type="radio" value="No">No</label>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Follow Up Phone Call</td>
        <td>Phone call</td>
        <td>
            <div class="radio" id="radio2">
                <label><input id="2" name="completed2" type="radio" value="Yes">Yes</label>
                <label><input checked id="2" name="completed2" type="radio" value="No">No</label>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I've got the basic script now being called when a user makes a change to one of the radio buttons - now I need to pass some parameters so I can update the correct record in the database and then update the class of the parent DIV so it shows red/green border as appropriate if there was/wasn't an error updating the database. Here's my script as it stands:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
        $.ajax({
        url: "updateTask.php",
        success: function(data) {
            $("#storeManager").html(data).addClass("has-success");
        },
        error: function (data) {
            $("#storeManager").html(data).addClass("has-error");
        }
        }); 
    });
});
```

I need to pass in the value from the selected radio button (e.g. 1 or 2 in the above example) as well as the ID for the radio button DIV (e.g. radio1 or radio2 in the above example). I stumped at this point.

Comment: use $(this)  to get the id and value

Comment: [Pass $.ajax() data](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to send `data` parameter along with the ajax call.
try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
        $.ajax({
        url: "updateTask.php",
        data: {
        id: $(this).closest('div').attr('id'),
        value: $(this).val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $("#storeManager").html(data).addClass("has-success");
        },
        error: function (data) {
            $("#storeManager").html(data).addClass("has-error");
        }
        }); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
        $.ajax({
        url: "updateTask.php",
        method: "POST",
       data: { name: "Yourname", location: "yourLocation" },
        success: function(data) {
            $("#storeManager").html(data).addClass("has-success");
        },
        error: function (data) {
            $("#storeManager").html(data).addClass("has-error");
        }
        }); 
    });
});
```

use data: to add your data